# Save State of WebView when switching Activity

Tags: android, webview, bundle

I am making a Web Browser that has some activities with WebView in them. Suppose I am in activity A, and when I switch to activity B and do some browsing there and I come back to activity A, the default URL is opened. I need a concrete solution to save my state in Bundle.

```
@Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "OnResume activity called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      if(webView_bundle!=null)
      {
          wv.restoreState(webView_bundle);
      }

   }
@Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onStart();

      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "OnPause activity called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          wv.saveState(webView_bundle);

   }
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    webView_bundle=(Bundle) outState.clone();
    wv.saveState(webView_bundle);
}
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    webView_bundle=(Bundle) savedInstanceState.clone();
    wv.restoreState(webView_bundle);
}
```

By the way, I am not using Fragments and using API 19, what should I do to save the state of the WebView of activity even after I switch to another activity and come back to this activity?

Comment: Did the below answer help,  Venkatesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling the following properties,in addition to the above code works like a charm :)

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
```

for each activity containing the WebView in AndroidManifest.xml worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

WebView doesn't properly restore its state. It's no bug. It's an intended change that promotes the privacy of the user's browsing activities. From the [WebView documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html):

> The standard behavior for an Activity is to be destroyed and recreated
>   when the device orientation or any other configuration changes. This
>   will cause the WebView to reload the current page. If you don't want
>   that, you can set your Activity to handle the orientation and
>   keyboardHidden changes, and then just leave the WebView alone. It'll
>   automatically re-orient itself as appropriate.

The only way to maintain state is to handle the configuration change yourself. Alternatively you could avoid using the standard WebView entirely and go for a custom one like [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/).